# Interface name in /etc/network/interfaces replaced with another interface name after reboot

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface, networkmanager

So I might have a rare corner case here, the thing is after rebooting my Debian 11 node the weirdest thing happened and that is the content of `/etc/network/interfaces` file has been altered, I have several actual interfaces and several virtual interfaces and `tun`s and the name of my primary interface hadn't changed after reboot in fact it was the same but it was replaced by one of the `tun` interfaces in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

I've done some research and every result points to the fact that interface names change from e.g. `eth0` to `eno1` and likes of that but in my case, the name was the same and was replaced by another interface name in the file.

Is there any explanation for this?

The following screenshot is the only evidence I have from this incident since I couldn't reproduce the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am in the process of scripting Debian 11.5 server installation. I spend 5 days troubleshooting network configuration. I learned that Debian network use systemd-networkd today and old ifupdown is translated to systemd. I decided to use systemd-networkd and within 1h all unexplained network issues gone. Yes the script syntax is not the same, but is similar.

Check your network status using networkctl:

```
networkctl -a status
```

https://manpages.debian.org/testing/systemd/systemd.network.5.en.html

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd-networkd

Comment: Dear @Bodgan_G, I will mark your answer as accepted since using `networkd` my problems regarding interface name changes, `systemctl restart networking` not working after configuring `bridge` and `bond` and all my automation problems such as Ansible or Scripting is gone, however, do you think migrating to `networkd` in production is a good idea? Do you have any resources saying `networkd` is production ready? Are there any bugs or known issues? Of course answering my questions is optional but it would be a great help and you'd have my appreciation.

Comment: Networking setup in Debian isn’t translated from `ifupdown` to `systemd-networkd` by default, you have to set it up that way if you want that to happen.

Comment: Hi @Skipper you have very good question of **"Do you have any resources saying networkd is production ready?" ** I put Linux servers starting 1993 and I am not expert!! Is ifupdown production ready??? NO it is not for Debian 11.5 as you can observe outburst of unexplained behaviors, in short unpredictable. I have not notice that from systemd-networkd. Production ready is when you test system to be stable, have control over its use, have control over updates, ... Is old system getting read flag? For me systemd-networkd is more production ready today, that my change tomorrow.

Comment: @Bogdan_G that was a fair and helpful answer thanks for taking the time.